# Plotting a contour and a line together in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, contour

I am trying to plot a contour from 3D data, where the contour will only on the base

```
set contour base
set cntrparam bspline
unset surface
set view map

splot 'file1.dat' u ($1):($2):($3) w l ls 1 notitle, \
      'file2.dat' u ($2):($3):(0) w lp ls 2
```

The second file is just a line which I want to plot in X-Y plane. However, since the surface is unset, the second plot does not show up. If I remove `unset surface` I see unwanted lines from the first file. Is there a solution to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably works (I don't have data to test with) if you use `nosurface` for the first and `nocontour` for the second plot:

```
set contour base
set cntrparam bspline
set view map

splot 'file1.dat' u 1:2:3 ls 1 w l nosurface notitle, \
      'file2.dat' u 2:3:(0) w lp ls 2 nocontour
```